# Comparing two char arrays and creating an Int array of the index of values that do not match up

Tags: java

I have two `char` arrays. One is the correct answers to the exam, `char[] answers` and the other is the `char[] studentAnswers`. I want to compare the two arrays and if there is an incorrect answer I want to store what questions they got wrong.

```
questionsMissed = i
questionsMissed = studentAnswers[i]

public int[] questionsMissed(char[] studentAnswers)
{
  for(int i = 0; i<studentAnswers.length; i++){
    if(studentAnswers[i] != answers[i]){
      questionsMissed =;
    }
  }
  return questionsMissed;
}
```

I want questionMissed to store the index of the char values that do not match.

Comment: Then simply allocate a new array of the same size as the number of questions.  All you need to to do is store a 1 in the proper slot for that value of `i` if they got the question wrong or  a 0 if they got it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need a `List` of `Integer` to add indexes and then convert it into `int` array

```
public int[] questionsMissed(char[] studentAnswers) {

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i<studentAnswers.length; i++){
   if(studentAnswers[i] != answers[i]){
      list.add(i);
     }
   }
 return list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

You can do this easily by using java-8 stream

```
int[] res = IntStream.range(0, studentAnswers.length)
                     .filter(i->studentAnswers[i] != answers[i])
                     .toArray();
```

If you you are on java-7 you need to iterate the list again

```
public int[] questionsMissed(char[] studentAnswers) {

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i<studentAnswers.length; i++){
   if(studentAnswers[i] != answers[i]){
      list.add(i);
     }
   }
    int[] arr = new int[list.size()];

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i]=list.get(i);
    }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: I have not learned java-8 stream yet as in my classes we have not gotten that far. Can you provide any answer without using this.

Comment: When I ran that it referenced the memory where it was stored and not the index of the incorrect question. This is what the textbook ask for. questionsMissed. An int array containing the question numbers of the questions that the student missed

Comment: Sorry i did not get your question @Ross

Answer (score 1):

It is easier if you use a list to append the indexes and return an `int` array at the end:

```
public int[] questionsMissed(char[] studentAnswers)
{
  List<Integer> questionsMissed  = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i = 0; i<studentAnswers.length; i++){
    if(studentAnswers[i] != answers[i]){
      questionsMissed.add(i);
    }
  }
  return questionsMissed.toArray();
}
```

Comment: List.toArray() returns object but not `int` array